# Netmiko goes to CONF T automatically! with ASA switches

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko, netmiko

This problem is not letting me sleep! Please help!
All I want is to: Connect to a Cisco-ASA and then go to Enable mode and then show interfaces status

The problem is, the following code is going to Enable mode and then automatically goes to CONF t mode which I don't need. I need it to stop at Enable mode.

```
def device1():

    checkOnline = {
        "device_type": "cisco_asa",
        "host": (swich1),
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
        'secret': password,
        'verbose': False,
        "session_log": 'dmz1_output.txt',
    }



    with ConnectHandler(**checkOnline) as net_connect:
        net_connect.enable()
        out1 = net_connect.send_command("show interface detail", use_textfsm=True)
        print(out1)
```

here is the log:

```
Failed logins since the last login: 0.  
Type help or '?' for a list of available commands.
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover> show curpriv
Current privilege level : 1
Current Mode/s : P_UNPR
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover> 
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover> 
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover> 
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover> 
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover> 
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover> 
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover> 
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover> 
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover> enable
Password: ************
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover# 
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover# terminal pager 0
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover# 
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover# configure terminal
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover(config)# 
Switch1/sec/actNoFailover(config)# terminal width 511
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `net_connect.send_command("exit")` before sending the `show interface detail` command? This is just a workaround. Unfortunately, I don't have an ASA to try it out.

Comment: Martin Prikryl - I canceled the script. Otherwise it would run the command

Comment: Tes3awy, Didn't work. It just goes into config mode. The problem is coming from this line 'secret': password,
Is there any command to force it to not to go to conf mode?

Comment: just remove : *** net_connect.enable() *** from your code

Answer (score 1):

It should automatically exit configuration mode after this i.e. after changing the terminal width, Netmiko will exit configuration mode. Alternatively you could set `allow_auto_change=False` as an argument to ConnectHandler (and then it won't change the terminal width).

This is assuming Netmiko 3.4.0

Comment: But is it gonna enter the conf t mode? Cause I don't even want it to do conf t. I only need Enable mode.

Comment: As per the above, set auto_allow_change=False and it won't change the terminal width automatically i.e. it won't go into config mode here.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. With 'terminal pager 0' there should be no need to do 'conf t'. This can be set directly in enable mode without going into configure mode.

Comment: The above log output does not enter `config mode` for `terminal pager 0` (only for setting the terminal width which you can disable with the `allow_auto_change=False` argument.